# How to send text area data with formatting to a database and retrieve it the same way

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am currently working on a project that has similar functionalities like Google Keep. For the To-Do functionality, the user will input his data in a list, preferably in a text area. I am not understanding in what way i should store the list in the database, so that when he tries to GET the data, it can be displayed with the same formatting. I will be using MongoDB, Node.JS and React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the user entered list (or any rich-text) store it in mongodb as HTML.
Check this article for more details about how to do it: [Link](https://www.tutorialswebsite.com/save-html-form-record-into-mongodb-database-using-express-js-and-mongoose-js/)
This should give you the flexibility to add meta-information about making the text bold, italic etc.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You can accept this answer if your question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and worked for me, give the div that's displaying the To-Dos a className eg todos

Then in index.css, insert this

```
.todos{
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```